# In classification, why is Decision boundary a property of hypothesis and not of training set?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I started watching ML videos of Andrew Ng on Coursera. In the lesson on Classification (in the third video), he said the following lines

"Once again, **the decision boundary is a property not of the training set, but of the hypothesis and of the parameters**.

But **once you have the parameters theta, that is what defines the decision boundary**."

My questions:

1. What is the difference between the training set and hypothesis?
2. Why is the decision boundary a property of hypothesis and not of training set?

Comment: This questions seems a better match to stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can think of it like this:

For any given set of parameters, there is a unique decision boundary. Hence the parameters *uniquely define* the decision boundary.

On the other hand, given training data, there is no unique decision boundary. You could select basically infinitely many different decision boundaries that fit to any one set of data. Hence the data cannot uniquely define the decision boundary, and hence the boundary cannot be a property of the data.

On the other hand, as he notes, you can use training data to select parameters, which then gives you a boundary. But there are many ways to do so.